# Binding two tableviews together but due to content row heights are different that causes index mismatch

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm working on javafx application and I needed fixed column in tableview  that's why I have binded two tables together and get it working but one table have only one column which contains only indexes and another table  has multiple columns and many data.

If any row has only one line data then rows of both tables having same height but in different case row has multiple lines then indexes are mismatched. I'm sharing my test code:

[image: screenshot of current issue]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author nitin
 */
public class NewClass extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Fix Column");
    Scene scene = new Scene(getView());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private BorderPane getView() {
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    List<Student> students = Student.getList();

    TableView<Student> fixedColumnTable = new TableView<>();
    fixedColumnTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(students));
    TableColumn<Student, Number> possionNumber = new TableColumn<>("#");
    possionNumber.setCellValueFactory(value -> value.getValue().getIdProperty());
    fixedColumnTable.getColumns().add(possionNumber);
    fixedColumnTable.setColumnResizePolicy(fixedColumnTable.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    fixedColumnTable.setPrefWidth(60);
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().add(fixedColumnTable);
    VBox.setVgrow(fixedColumnTable, Priority.ALWAYS);
    HBox.setHgrow(fixedColumnTable, Priority.ALWAYS);
    borderPane.setLeft(vBox);
    Region region = new Region();

    TableView<Student> table = new TableView<>();
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(students));

    table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Student>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Student item, boolean empty) {
            setRowHight(fixedColumnTable, table);
        }
    });

    TableColumn<Student, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(value -> value.getValue().getNameProperty());

    TableColumn<Student, Number> ageCol = new TableColumn<>("Age");
    ageCol.setCellValueFactory(value -> value.getValue().getAgeProperty());

    TableColumn<Student, String> courseCol = new TableColumn<>("Course");
    courseCol.setCellValueFactory(value -> value.getValue().getCourseProperty());

    table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, ageCol, courseCol);
    borderPane.setCenter(table);

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        ScrollBar fixColtableVerticalBar = (ScrollBar) fixedColumnTable.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
        fixColtableVerticalBar.setPrefWidth(0);
        fixColtableVerticalBar.setMaxWidth(0);
        fixColtableVerticalBar.setVisible(false);
        fixColtableVerticalBar.setOpacity(1);
        ScrollBar tableVerticalBar = (ScrollBar) table.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
        tableVerticalBar.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(fixColtableVerticalBar.valueProperty());

        ObservableList<Node> list = vBox.getChildren();
        Set<Node> scrollBars = table.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
        Optional<Node> horizontalScrollBar = scrollBars.stream()
                .filter(node
                        -> ((ScrollBar) node).getOrientation().equals(Orientation.HORIZONTAL))
                .findAny();
        horizontalScrollBar.ifPresent(node
                -> node.visibleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (newValue && !list.contains(region)) {
                        list.add(region);
                        Platform.runLater(() -> region.setMinHeight(((ScrollBar) node).getHeight()));
                    } else {
                        list.remove(region);
                    }
                })
        );

    });

    return borderPane;
}

private void setRowHight(TableView t1, TableView t2) {
    List<Node> leftTableRows = new ArrayList(t1.lookupAll(".table-row-cell"));
    List<Node> rightTableRows = new ArrayList(t2.lookupAll(".table-row-cell"));
    if (leftTableRows.size() == rightTableRows.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < leftTableRows.size(); i++) {
            TableRow leftTableRow = (TableRow) leftTableRows.get(i);
            TableRow leftRow = (TableRow) leftTableRows.get(i);
            TableRow rightRow = (TableRow) rightTableRows.get(i);
            leftRow.setPrefHeight(rightRow.getHeight());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}

class Student {

private int id;
private String name;
private int age;
private String course;

public Student(int id, String name, int age, String course) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.course = course;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public IntegerProperty getIdProperty() {
    return new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public StringProperty getNameProperty() {
    return name != null ? new SimpleStringProperty(name) : null;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public IntegerProperty getAgeProperty() {
    return new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public StringProperty getCourseProperty() {
    return course != null ? new SimpleStringProperty(course) : null;
}

public static List<Student> getList() {
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Student(0, "A", 18, "Java \n sfsf\n sdfsdf\ndsfsfsd : "));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        list.add(new Student(i, "A" + i, 18, "Java : " + i));
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get each row of each table. Then set the left height based on the right height.

```
private void setRowHight(TableView t1, TableView t2) {
    List<Node> leftTableRows = new ArrayList(t1.lookupAll(".table-row-cell"));
    List<Node> rightTableRows = new ArrayList(t2.lookupAll(".table-row-cell"));

    for (Node tableRow : rightTableRows) {
        TableRow<?> r = (TableRow<?>) tableRow;
        for (Node tableRowLeft : leftTableRows) {
            TableRow<?> l = (TableRow<?>) tableRowLeft;
                if (r.getIndex() == l.getIndex()) {
                    l.setPrefHeight(r.getHeight());
                    break;
                }
            }
    }    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sedrick, Thanks for reply it's working but if i scroll table horizontally than its not align properly and indexes gone again mismatch please check...!

Comment: I have added VBox in index cell and update VBox height according to row Height and now working fine thank you @Sedrick for your help.